# NativeScript Vue cannot import component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript-vue

I'm new to using NativeScript and trying to build my first program with it.  I am attempting to import a header component into my main App. When I run my ios emulator I cannot see a header.

I have my App component:

```
<template>
  <Page>
    <Header :numCorrect="numCorrect" :numTotal="numTotal" />
    <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
      <Label class="message" :text="msg" col="0" row="0" />
    </GridLayout>
  </Page>
</template>

<script >
import Header from "./Header.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "click me",
      questions: [],
      index: 0,
      numCorrect: 0,
      numTotal: 0
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.message {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20;
  color: #333333;
}
</style>
```

and my Header component:

```
<template>
  <StackLayout class="nav" orientation="vertical">
    <span class="title">Quiz App</span>
    <span class="title">Counter : 0/0</span>
  </StackLayout>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Header",
  props: ["numCorrect", "numTotal"]
};
</script>

<style scoped>
nav {
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

I feel like I have tried everything to display the header but still no luck. Am I missing something obvious?  Again very new to NativeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the nativescript-vue community. Your Header component doesn't include a valid nativescript element to display.  Replace your `<span>` tags with `<Label>` tags:

```
<template>
  <StackLayout class="nav" orientation="vertical">
    <Label text="Quiz App" />
    <Label text="Counter : 0/0" />
  </StackLayout>
</template>
```

If you want to include the props in the counter, you can do the following:

```
<template>
  <StackLayout class="nav" orientation="vertical">
    <Label text="Quiz App" />
    <Label :text="`Counter : ${numCorrect}/${numTotal}`" />
  </StackLayout>
</template>
```